# add period after cite entry

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

I would like to add a period after an entry introduced by `\cite`. I'm using `biblatex`.

So far I only found ways of changing the ending of `\autocite`  using `\bibfootnotewrapper`. Is there a similar wrapper one can control for `\cite`?

Example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

%compiled with "latexmk -xelatex"

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes, natbib,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,omitxrefdate=false, backend=bibtex, clearlang=true]{biblatex-chicago}  
\bibliography{lib.bib}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\cite{goossens93}. Something something} 
\autocite{goossens93}
\end{document}
```

Where lib.bib would be:

```
@book{goossens93,
author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
year = "1993",
publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
address = "Reading, Massachusetts"}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal working example we can work with. Also, this may possibly clarify your question which isn't really one I understand at this point. Why would you want it always followed by a full stop? What if it is not the end of a sentence? What happens if it is a question rather than a statement?

Comment: If nothing else, you need to (1) explain what biblatex citation style you use and (2) provide a bit more of an explanation of why you need this -- how are you using the command which leads to this requirement.

Comment: I'm using biblatex-chicago. \autocite does its job for most of the things I need, but sometimes I need to explain something in my footnotes, and add a citation. In these cases I would like the citation to automatically end in a period. I agree that changing the whole behavior of \cite might not be a good idea. I have tried creating a new command `\newcommand{\citep}[1]{\cite{#1}\addperiod}` but this puts my citation in parentheses.

Comment: `\autocite{....}` ends in a period, while `\footnote{\autocite{....}}` doesn't. What do you think is the best solution?

Comment: I can't get your example to compile at all. Once I run `bibtex`, that's it. Any attempt to compile ends in error. Please edit to correct your code.

Comment: I compiled the code with `latexmk -xelatex` but I don't know if that matters.

Comment: I remember (vaguely) the author of `biblatex-chicago` writing in the documentation that getting final periods in automatically was tricky and that he removed the implementation because it would too often *wrongly* add a period when one was not called for.

Comment: I can't get the code to compile with `backend=bibtex` at all. Does it work for @jon? I tried pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr -- hmm, you're right. I'm getting an error about `\cms@choose/global` being undefined. (I don't normally use the `notes` style or BibTeX, so this is new to me.) (The error is common across engines.)

Comment: I can only compile it with XeLaTex not with pdfLaTex

Comment: For my earlier comment, see page 67 of the docs (for version `1.0rc1 (beta)`).

Comment: @jon Me, too. I don't use `biblatex-chicago` any longer and I never used `notes`. However, I always used `bibtex` with it. (This is why I stopped using it - I could no longer typeset author-year with it, lacking Biber at the time.) @ igm2103 I get the same error as jon with both engines.

Comment: Are you sure that ***exactly the code you posted compiles*** for you  after running `bibtex`? That is, not your original document, but this one?

Comment: @jon, thank you for the reference that explains the weird behavior of citations in footnotes.  @cfr Yes, the code I have in the example compiles without errors when I use `latexmk -xelatex`

Comment: So it sounds like there's a version thing going on. Can you check what version of `biblatex-chicago` you are using? For me, `\listfiles` prints `biblatex-chicago.sty    2016/06/01 v 3.4` in the `.log`.

Comment: Package: biblatex-chicago 2014/08/15 v 2.9a biblatex style

Comment: Well, it looks (in my version of `biblatex-chicago.sty`) like the way `\cms@choose` is used has grown in complexity since then. Until this error is fixed (for newer versions) I  can't help you with your problem.  In my opinion, however, `\footnote{\cite{goossens93}. Something something}` is the right input syntax, and I don't think it is worth the trouble to get the period automatically (mainly because I think the resulting code will be like a rickety Rube Goldberg machine that is liable to break at any minute).

Comment: However, I should add that, as you probably concluded yourself, you may not want to update `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` until you are sure that the current error is fixed. (If, that is, you need the `notes` Chicago style.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with those who have commented above. I don't see what you gain from a special command by not just adding the period manually.

But you *could* abuse `\autocites` in this way :)

I make a new delimiter:

```
\newcommand*{\multipostnotedelim}{\addperiod\space}
```

Then fiddle with the `multipostnote` format so it capitalises automatically:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1}}{#1}}
```

Then patch the the `multipostnote` macro to use our new `\multipostnotedelim`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{multipostnote}
  {\postnotedelim}{\multipostnotedelim}{}{}
```

And you then you can do this:

```
Filler text \autocites(something something)[12]{goossens93}.
```

Giving you this output:

[image]

Comment: how would I apply this solution to a bibliography entry in biblatex? I have an online entry in my .bib file and the last field is the urldate. Unfortunately, latex does not place a period after the urldate. This causes the following back reference not to be capitalized. I posted my MWE here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657138/tufte-latex-vertical-adjustment-of-biblatex-citations-in-captions/657466#657466

Comment: I created a paired down modifiable MWE on overleaf:  https://www.overleaf.com/6514453265gbtcvtrmpjnw

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `\punctcite` command that is a copy of `\cite`, but with a wrapper around it that adds a full stop after the citation.

```
\newcommand{\bibpunctwrapper}[1]{%
  \bibsentence#1\addperiod}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\punctcite}[\bibpunctwrapper]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Here `\bibpunctwrapper` is a copy of `\bibfootnoterwapper` (I used a new command in order to be able to use the two independently). And `\punctcite` is just a copy of `chicago-notes`' `\cite` with just the optional argument `[\bibpunctwrapper]` added.

Use it as

```
\footnote{\punctcite{companion} Something something}
```

to obtain

> Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin, The LaTeX Companion, 1st ed. (Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1994). Something something

in the footnote

Comment: how would I apply this solution or perhaps the one above it to a bibliography entry in biblatex? I have an online entry in my .bib file and the last field is the urldate. Unfortunately, latex does not place a period after the urldate. This causes the following back reference not to be capitalized. I posted my MWE here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657138/tufte-latex-vertical-adjustment-of-biblatex-citations-in-captions/657466#657466

Comment: I created a paired down modifiable MWE on overleaf:  https://www.overleaf.com/6514453265gbtcvtrmpjnw